# Manifolds with boundary and definition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

Can you help for understanding this definitions in a good way.What is the my problem is that I can not image this definition and proposition in my mind and also ı dont understand the reason that ı write gren writing.Also what is actually $i_{x}w$.These are basi thinks but can someone give me light these definition and propostiton,I will so happy thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation form is defined as an every where non-zero n form.

This means that its value on any n linearlly independent vectors is always non-zero.

The boundary of the manifold has a unit inward point normal vector. At each point of the boundary the unit normal can be extended to n linearly independent vectors by adding any n-1 linearly independent vectors that are tangent to the boundary. The orientation form on the manifold is never zero on these n frames and thus defines by contraction with the unit normal an orientation form on the boundary